# Union ALL multiple query Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have three queries with the same column count and structure, does Google BigQuery support union all? I know it supports union but I need it to merge the result of the query into one result.

I have tried:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(SELECT a.a AS a, a.b AS b, d.c AS c FROM table_a a JOIN table_d d on d.a = a.a),
(SELECT c.a AS a, c.b AS b, d.c AS c FROM table_c c JOIN table_d d on d.a = ca.a),
(SELECT b.a AS a, b.b AS b, d.c AS c FROM table_b b JOIN table_d d on d.a = b.a)
```

I get the following error:

```
Union results in ambiguous schema [d.c] is ambiguous and is aliasing multiple fields
```

Thanks For your help.

Comment: Can you share a sample of the dataset publicly? Stackoverflowers will be happy to help with a working query - and it will be easier to test with the actual data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I can't really share a sample of the dataset, it's a normal table not nested, and the data is loaded in from a csv file, into BigQuery. If that helps

Comment: Please share your dataset id name, and proper queries, and BQ team will probably pick this up, and will be able to answer you.

Comment: I will see what I can do. At the moment I just need to know how to do a union all in BigQuery.

Comment: Are each of the subqueries working in isolation?

Comment: You are doing unions right. You don't need to share your data - but at least create an empty replica of your tables and share that to facilitate helping out with this case.

Comment: Hi Rohit, yeap each query works when I run them by them self. Hi Felipe I'm not 100% sure how to do union in BigQuery. If I don't get a solution by Monday Them I will share the table structure. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Must you know if the data are come from table a, b or c? If you don't need to know, you can try the following query:

```
select *
from
(select a, b
from table_a, table_b, table_c) as a
join
(select a, c
from table_d) as d 
on a.a = d.a
```